# Upload HTML to S3 Bucket using AWS SDK Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am creating a project to scrape the source code of an website using `puppeteer-core` and `chrome-aws-lambda`.

The idea of the project is to scrape the page source and put that content into `S3` bucket as `source.txt` , for few websites it works fine but for some it is creating an empty text file. I am sure i am getting the source the issue happen while putting it to S3
My basic code is

```
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
S3.putObject({
        Bucket: S3Bucket,
        Key: `${unique_id}/source.txt`,
        Body: new Buffer.from((pageSource)),
        CacheControl: "max-age=0,no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate",
        ContentType: "text/html",
      }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          console.log(data)
        }

      })
```

It is putting empty file into the s3 for some URL's

My packages are

```
"aws-sdk": "^2.756.0",
"chrome-aws-lambda": "^5.3.1",
"puppeteer-core": "^5.5.0",
```

Comment: Reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property , the putObject comment says "Amazon S3 never adds partial objects; if you receive a success response, Amazon S3 added the entire object to the bucket." Also, the documentation suggest to use MD5 checksums to make sure that s3 stored what you expect. If your md5 matches the returned value I would rather focus on issues on the client side.

Comment: When i tried the same using Python boto3 it works perfectly fine , while using nodejs client it is not working

Comment: @petrch I am going through that trying to implement the same , thank you for your response